# Java ByteBuffer class

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I'm reading a byte[] from a device and trying to interpret it as an integer array in Java with the help of the ByteBuffer class but I'm getting an index out of bounds error. Look here:

```
byteBuffer.put(bytes); // put the array of bytes into the byteBuffer        

System.out.println("the value I want is " + byteBuffer.getInt(16*4)); // gives me the number I want, but I'd rather deal with an integer array like this:

System.out.println("the value I want is " + byteBuffer.asIntBuffer().get(16)); // index out of bounds? Why??
```

Comment: Can you post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I found out it works if I do a byteBuffer.position(0) before I call byteBuffer.asIntBuffer(). Seems weird to have to do that but it works.

Comment: Probably because the position of the ByteBuffer is changed. In the javadoc for `asIntBuffer`: The content of the new buffer will start at this buffer's current position. Changes to this buffer's content will be visible in the new buffer, and vice versa; the two buffers' position, limit, and mark values will be independent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ByteBuffer` class internally stores several properties of the buffer. The most important one being the *position* (of a virtual "cursor") in the buffer. This position can be read with `byteBuffer.position()`, and written with `byteBuffer.position(123);`.

The JavaDoc of [`ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer--) now states:

> The content of the new buffer will start at this buffer's current position.

This means that, for example, when you have a `ByteBuffer` with a capacity of 16 elements, and the `position()` of this `ByteBuffer` is 4, then the resulting `IntBuffer` will only represent the remaining 12 elements.

After calling `byteBuffer.put(bytes)`, the *position* of the byte buffer is advanced (depending on the length of the byte array). The `IntBuffer` that you are creating then has a smaller capacity, accordingly.

To solve this, you can call `byteBuffer.rewind()` or `byteBuffer.position(0)` after you called `byteBuffer.put(bytes)`. (Which one is more appropriate depends on the intended usage pattern)